# How to Retrieve MapRunArn and ResultWriterDetails in AWS Step Functions Catch Block to pass it to further step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm currently working on a project involving AWS Step Functions and are in the process of implementing a global error handling mechanism. Our solution is based on AWS CDK, and we're utilizing a distributed map. To manage errors that arise within the ItemProcessor, we're using the ResultsWriter to write to an S3 bucket and capturing errors using the Catch block.

However, I've encountered an issue where catching errors in the Catch block leads to a loss of crucial information, such as the "MapRunArn," which is essential for identifying the correct results stored in S3 by the ResultsWriter.

As an example, consider the simplified Step Functions definition below (not using CDK):

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "TestDistributedMap",
  "States": {
    "TestDistributedMap": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        },
        "StartAt": "Fail",
        "States": {
          "Fail": {
            "Type": "Fail"
          }
        }
      },
      "Label": "TestDistributedMap",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1000,
      "ResultWriter": {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:putObject",
        "Parameters": {
          "Bucket": "<some-bucket>",
          "Prefix": "testDistributedMap"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Pass (1)",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Pass (1)",
          "ResultPath": "$"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Pass (1)": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

When running this, the Pass (1) state receives the following input upon failure:

```
{
  "Error": "States.ExceedToleratedFailureThreshold",
  "Cause": "The specified tolerated failure threshold was exceeded"
}
```

However, if the map run succeeds, we receive:

```
{
  "MapRunArn": "<maprun-arn>",
  "ResultWriterDetails": {
    "Bucket": "someBucket",
    "Key": "testDistributedMap/<distributed-maprun-id>/manifest.json"
  }
}
```

From my perspective, this behavior is unexpected because I can't properly identify the correct results.

Ideally, I would like the option to receive the MapRunArn (along with ResultWriterDetails) in the error handling scenario for further processing.

Am I missing something in my implementation? How can I address this issue?